# How to add space in WordPress post content without adding a new line

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets document with content that goes into a WordPress post. I am trying to add non-breaking space inside the formulas. The problem is that when I add the non-breaking space I need to create it on a new line. Example:

`&nbsp;This is random text which I need to break &nbsp; (Doesn't work)`

This works

`&nbsp;
This is random text which I need to break
&nbsp;`

If I break the text with the `&nbsp;` above and below text, the google sheets formula wraps the entire text inside double quotation marks, something I want to avoid. Also, adding this `&nbsp;` between text doesn't create space where the entity has been added.

In short, what I am looking for is a way to create non-breaking blank space between two sentences where `&nbsp;` appears. So that this random `&nbsp;` text here becomes this

So that this random

now breaks and leaves a blank space like so

My google sheets formula is something like this but you don't  have to use it  `="<h1>"&CONCATENATE(UPPER(A2 &" and " &C2)&" This is Random text")&"</h1><b>"&UPPER(A2 &" and " &C2)&"</b>"&A1&"Date: "&TEXT(BT2,"dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")&"<br>Examples at "&B2&" NOW &nbsp; <b>"&A2&"</b> vs <b>"&C2&"</b> for "&A1&" time period.`

Link to google sheets document https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qdyMPqbIg6tUOOPrHDoVqzHpQKQhLh4_BT8IhsjE2ig/edit?usp=sharing
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE("<h1>"&UPPER(A2&" and "&C2)&" This is Random text"&
 "</h1><b>"&UPPER(A2&" and "&C2)&"</b>"&A1&"Date: "&TEXT(BT2, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")&
 "<br>Examples at "&B2&" NOW &nbsp; <b>"&A2&"</b> vs <b>"&C2&"</b> for "&A1&" time period.",
 "(&nbsp;)", CHAR(10)&"$1")
```

[image]

---

to avoid wrapping the copied string into double quotes use:

```
={""; REGEXREPLACE("<h1>"&UPPER(A2&" and "&C2)&" This is Random text"&
 "</h1><b>"&UPPER(A2&" and "&C2)&"</b>"&A1&"Date: "&TEXT(BT2, "dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")&
 "<br>Examples at "&B2&" NOW &nbsp; <b>"&A2&"</b> vs <b>"&C2&"</b> for "&A1&" time period.",
 "(&nbsp;)", CHAR(10)&"$1")}
```

one step further would be entering the cell before copying it...

- select cell
- press <kbd>**`ENTER`**</kbd>
- press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`A`**</kbd>
- press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`C`**</kbd>

Comment: Still wraps the text in double quotes

Comment: Unfortunately, when I import the content, it carries together with the double quotes. All my other formulas don't wrap the text in quotes. Not sure why this is happening.